# Are there any tools for debugging imap?

Tags: imap, telnet

Not sure if the library I use to work with imap is working correctly. Constantly shaping queries using telnet or openssl is a bit tedious. Maybe there is some sort of tool that will make this job easier in terms of prepared queries, etc.?

Comment: Python imaplib is very low level, and can be used to fire queries off to a server in a pinch.

Comment: Imaplib does not fully implement imap, there is no rfc2971 implementation seen there. Yes the command is not obligatory, but I met imap servers which did not work without it.

Comment: You can send any (simple) command with `xatom`, which covers ID just fine.  Turn on debug level to see responses.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try

Comment: @max, xatom command is quite strange works. I tried to execute `imap.xatom ('ID ("name" "name" "version" 1.0.0")')`, but somehow imaplib thinks that the ID command is sent after selecting the folder: `command ID ("NAME" "name" "version" "1.0.0") illegal in state AUTH, only allowed in States SELECTED`. It's actually not, the **ID** is sent immediately after **LOGIN**, judging from other email clients.

Comment: That's the server, I think  In Python 3.6.4:  ```>>> x = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
>>> x.xatom('ID', '("name" "name")')
('OK', [b'Success u11mb830940600jag'])```  I have certainly seen servers want ID in weird states.  Some servers want it BEFORE login, some after,

Comment: It might be filling in it's state array from the servers CAPABILITY response.  I'm not sure how it's doing that.  `del imaplib.Commands['ID']` is a hack that will allow you to send it, even if it thinks you shouldn't, or set it manually to states you think you should be able to send it in.

Answer (score 0):

We had an issue where a client's program was accessing an IMAP server and would not see anything but there was mail in the mailbox.  Ultimately it was a poisoned DNS issue that  I  won't get into here, but... along the way we used PHP 7.3.11 and this script to view the contents of mailboxes, etc.  And this should be a good starting point.  It  allowed us to prove the IMAP server was operating properly and we could see all along what it was doing.

We could go back and tweak the script to see different results, etc.

This is a  READ-ONLY script.  You can run it  against any  mailbox  to which you  personally have access and see what it does.

> ***NOTE** This is looking at the mailbox "INBOX.3 Followup", you can and it displays all subject lines of all messages in that INBOX.  You
> can change that to something else such as just "INBOX" or "SENT", etc.

---

```
<?php

// Email credentials
$email = 'john@doe.com';
$password = 'password';
$server = '{imap.server.com/novalidate-cert/notls:993/ssl}INBOX.3 Followup';

// Connect to the IMAP server
$mailbox = imap_open($server, $email, $password);

if ($mailbox) 
        {
        // Search for all emails
        // $emails = imap_search($mailbox, 'ALL');
        $emails = imap_search($mailbox,'ALL');
        if ($emails) 
                {
                // Iterate through each email
                foreach ($emails as $email_id) 
                        {
                        $header = imap_headerinfo($mailbox, $email_id);
                        $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($header->date));
                        $subject = $header->subject;
                        echo "Email ID: $email_id\n";
                        echo "Date: $date\n";
                        echo "Subject: $subject\n";
                        echo "----------------------------------\n";
                        };
                } 
        else 
                {
                echo "No emails found.\n";
                };
        // Close the mailbox
        imap_close($mailbox);
        } 
else 
        {
        echo "Failed to connect to the mailbox.\n";
        };
?>
```

---

Thanks,
David

Comment: Are you saying that you reacted to poison by sending your password somewhere, *in cleartext?*

Comment: @arnt, absolutely  not.    They were complete  separate issues and the  above is just an example.  Just trying to give other something to work with other than "good luck".

Answer (score -1):

The IMAP's grammar is pretty irregular (in terms of data that are returned by the server). There's no fancy tool to offer, e.g., pre-made response parsing. And if there was one, you could have just as well used it directly :).